# Strange behaviour for simple string table in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to store md5 checksums in an sqlite table, and it works well almost all the time (for tens of thousands of files). But for one specific file, things turn weird. It seems to me like the checksum in the example below has some "magic" qualities that confuses sqlite.

```
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> CREATE TABLE files (md5 STRING UNIQUE NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO files (md5) values ("8534112824210843669373e916873875");
sqlite> INSERT INTO files (md5) values ("9534112824210843669373e916873875");
SQL error: column md5 is not unique
sqlite> SELECT * FROM files;
Inf
sqlite>
```

Note that the second string is similar, but clearly different. You can try with just about any other strings and it works fine. What is the reason for this behaviour? Have I found a bug in sqlite?

**Solved** The "STRING" column type, for whatever reason, has "numeric affinity" in sqlite, meaning it will be interpreted as a number if possible. The correct way to do what I want is to use the "TEXT" column type. Thanks for the answers anyway!

Comment: Don't know about sqlite, but normal sql strings are in single quotes. So your values seem to be interpreted as numbers in scientific format (1e345) and give infinify.

Comment: Solved! See question for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `STRING` column type, for whatever reason, has "numeric affinity" in SQLite, meaning it will be interpreted as a number, if possible.

The checksum `8534112824210843669373e916873875` resembles a float value since it happens to contain a single `e` (making it look like a float using exponent notation). So, as a result, it does get interpreted as a number.

The correct way to store a normal text string is to use the `TEXT` column type.

Comment: The reason `STRING` has numeric affinity is because [it's not a type that SQLite recognizes](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity). You can have a column type `BANANA` and its affinity will also be numeric. SQLite doesn't error on unknown types.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that you should be using single quotes rather than double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO files (md5) values ('8534112824210843669373e916873875');
INSERT INTO files (md5) values ('9534112824210843669373e916873875');
```

This is the proper delimiter for a string.

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), when you put something in double quotes it is treated as an identifier.  Those two values happen to look like very large floating point numbers, in pseudo-scientific format -- you know, 6.023e23 is a valid number.  My guess is that these are getting converted to either the largest floating point value or to not-a-number, so both are equal.

After a little testing on SQLFiddle, this behavior seems to be how strings work.  Consider:

```
select 1e2  --> 100
select '1e2'  --> 1e2
select cast('1e2' as string)  --> 100
select cast('1e2' as varchar(255))  --> 1e2
```

Can you change the data type in the table from string to varchar?  This is because string has an affinity to numeric, to to varchar (according to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).

Comment: Great insight! Makes a lot of sense

Comment: Unfortunately my example behaves exactly the same after replacing double quotes with single quotes. :(